# How to stop chrome from downloading unwanted assets?

Tags: google-chrome, safari, webkit, mobify-js

In previous version of chrome, on a webpage with the following:

```
<script>
   document.write('<plaintext>');
</script>

<img src="http://example.com/image.jpg">
```

the image would not be downloaded. At some point a chrome update changed this behavior. Now when I look at the network tab, I see the image is downloaded. (fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/doojunqx/)

I have a script that is on a page, I would like to use this script to stop the browser from downloading (using up network bandwidth) for images and other assets that are unwanted and below my script tag.

Mobify does something similar here: 
http://cdn.mobify.com/mobifyjs/examples/capturing-grumpycat/index.html

As they say on the page "Open your web inspector and note the original imgs did not load." However, when I open chrome developer tools and look at the network tab, I see the original images ARE now loading. I'm not sure what version of chrome changed this, but I think it is recent, within the last month or two.

Is there any way to force chrome back to the old behavior? Or any other way to stop these unwanted assets from loading?

Thanks,

Comment: It looks like the problem is the preload scanner. In previous versions of chrome the preload scanner would stop if there was a render blocking script in the head.

Is there any way to disable the preload scanner?

Answer (score 3):

Great question, and you're correct that it is [a recent change in Chromium](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=421289) that affected the plaintext tag behaviour. In versions up to and including version 42.*, the HTML document parser would not spawn an asynchronous parsing thread until an external resource was found in the original HTML document. Once such a resource was found, an asynchronous thread would be spawned that would aggressively download all resources references within the HTML.

The recent change simplified the parsing behaviour by moving all document parsing to the asynchronous thread which now kicks off automatically. Whereas before, using the plaintext tag would ensure that no resources would be loaded if it was inserted before the first external resource, the plaintext tag is now racy as resources will download up to the moment the plaintext tag is executed in the main HTML document. As there is a time delay for the script to execute, an unknown number of resources will be retrieved.

There is as of yet no solution to this new behaviour, nor is there a way to disable the preload scanner as you would like. You will need to rely on workarounds such as polyfills to control your resource downloads. This new behaviour is only present in all versions of Chrome >= 43.* and has not been implemented in Safari, Firefox, or other browsers.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation Dan.

Do you have any polyfills in mind to control resource downloads?

Comment: The easiest way to control resource downloads is to actually just use non-standard attributes like `x-src` instead of `src`. Just do a test in JavaScript to decide which of the resources to download and switch the attribute back to `src` on the appropriate resources.